# Entity State for entity framework with repositories

Tags: entity-framework, repository

I am using Julie Lerman's EF Repository techniques.

All my entities implement the following interface

```
public interface IEntity
{
    EntityState State { get; set; }
}
```

All my repositories call the following GetList function

```
    public virtual IList<T> GetList(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        List<T> list;
        IQueryable<T> dbQuery = ((DbContext)context).Set<T>();

        //Apply eager loading
        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            dbQuery = dbQuery.Include(navigationProperty);
        }

        list = dbQuery.AsNoTracking().Where(where).ToList();

        return list;
    }
```

I am finding that the initial state property for my entities is zero, but I want to set it to 
I want to set State property to be EntityState.Unchanged

How should I do this?

Comment: How about do foreach to the list then set the state to unchanged `foreach(var item in list) item.State = EntityState.Unchaged;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julie Lerman described it in her book `Programming Entity Framework: DbContext` At page 93
(Example 4-15).

You can use following code in your `DbContext constractor` to set the object states to `UnChanged`:

```
public YourContext() 
{
  ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext .ObjectMaterialized +=
    (sender, args) =>
    {
       var entity = args.Entity as IEntity; 
       if (entity != null)
       {
          entity.State = State.Unchanged;
       }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another easier approach to this issue. I am using it and it works!!

```
public abstract class Entity<TId> : BaseEntity, IEntity<TId>, IModelState
{
    public virtual TId Id { get; private set; }

    public byte[] RowVersion { get; protected set; }

    private readonly IDictionary<Type, IEvent> events = new Dictionary<Type, IEvent>();

    public IEnumerable<IEvent> Events => events.Values;
```

**public ModelState ModelState { get; protected set; } = ModelState.Unchanged;**

```
    protected Entity()
    {
        ModelState = ModelState.Added;
    }

... removed for brevity
```

make sure you're using C# 7 and Roslyn Compiler with your .NET 4.6.x

I think this is safer because only your own Entity Object will have the power to set it to unchanged when it gets initialized by EF.  In my opinion DbContext should not have the right to set the "state" property of any entity.